# choose between discrete distributions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics, distribution

I am trying to choose the best fit between discrete distributions but I get an error below that discrete dists have no attribute fit. Anyone has any idea how to fix this or any alternative ways to choose between discrete distributions?

```
import scipy.stats as st
def get_best_distribution(data):
    dist_names = ["bernoulli", "poisson", "binom", "geom", "logser", "randint"]
    dist_results = []
    params = {}
    for dist_name in dist_names:
        dist = getattr(st, dist_name)
        param = dist.fit(data)

        params[dist_name] = param
        # Applying the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
        D, p = st.kstest(data, dist_name, args=param)
        print("p value for "+dist_name+" = "+str(p))
        dist_results.append((dist_name, p))

    # select the best fitted distribution
    best_dist, best_p = (max(dist_results, key=lambda item: item[1]))
    # store the name of the best fit and its p value

    print("Best fitting distribution: "+str(best_dist))
    print("Best p value: "+ str(best_p))
    print("Parameters for the best fit: "+ str(params[best_dist]))

    return best_dist, best_p, params[best_dist]
print(get_best_distribution(df)

AttributeError: 'bernoulli_gen' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

Comment: You could construct a [Chi-squared goodness of fit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test).

Answer (score 0):

Only continuous distributions can be fitted in `SciPy`. Discrete and multivariate distributions do not support such a feature.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any equivalent way to choose between discrete in python?

Comment: @Uni 13 , I do not know statistics so well to guess why exactly fit is not implemented for discrete distrs. But I think for some reason you have to find parameters of distrs manually.